# Does a 32bit move zero out higher bits in a 64bit register?

Tags: x86, zero-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-register)

If I do a `movl something, %eax` and `rax` contained something like 0x1234567812345678, will it automatically zero out the top half of `rax`?

Comment: Thanks, if you post it as an answer, I'll be able to accept it

Comment: I could do that, but there's a more interesting answer (including likely reasons) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-register